# Imgur API Version 3 JavaScript upload example

Tags: javascript, jquery, imgur

All the examples I find online are of earlier versions of the Imgur API or non JS code all of which uses an API key which doesn't exist in the newer API. Instead you get a `client_id` and `secret`. Anyone have example code that shows how an image can be uploaded to Imgur through JavaScript (or jQuery) using version 3 of their API?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Client-ID YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
    },
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        'image': 'helloworld.jpg'
    },
    success: function() { console.log('cool'); }
});
```

Comment: I get this message: " POST https://api.imgur.com/3/image 403 (Permission Denied)  "

Comment: @vin awesome thanks so much. Been confused about this for weeks.

Comment: @acudars did you change this part: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID" with the client id you recieved after registering your app here https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/addclient ?

Comment: why the response I get is 1203 image over capacity? even after I used a very small image?

Comment: @vin Why i have error? `$.ajax({ 
                url: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': '6b72b886602****'
                },
                type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                    'image': '111.PNG'
                    },
            success: function() { console.log('cool'); }
            });`

Comment: I sill get permission denied after putting my own client id as well.

Comment: Im getting error 429, SO link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66873683/unable-to-post-image-to-imgur-api-with-axios-post?noredirect=1

Answer (score 0):

Building on @vin's example here is one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Client-ID a1b2c3d4e5'
        },
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'image': image
        },
        success: function(data, status) {
            console.log("Data: " + data.data.link + "\nStatus: " status);
            console.log(data.data.link)
        }
    });
});
```

This lets you save the url to the file.